# Howto recognize documents in Alfresco 5.0 and filing them according content?

Tags: alfresco

I have following use case:

1. Existing scanner scans documents and stores them via WebDAV or a shared network drive to Alfresco
2. Documents are separated with a barcode to identify the customer and document type (e.g. bill)
3. If a document arrives in the shared drive, Alfresco should analyse it and move it (according customer and document type) to the suitable internal folder structure.

Example of a folder structure:

- /scans/
- /customers/ExampleCustomer1/bills
- /customers/ExampleCustomer1/emails
- /customers/ExampleCustomer1/hr
- /customers/ExampleCustomer2/bills
- /customers/ExampleCustomer2/emails
- /customers/ExampleCustomer2/hr

Question:

- What do I need in Alfresco to process step 3) to automatically recognize documents and file them?

P.s. I know there exists applications like Ephesoft/Kofax but I would like to have a module inside Alfresco which does the job for me without external dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the following sequence:

1)Your scanner or other (OCR) software needs to interprete the barcode and save the customer and type somewhere in the document, for example in docx metadata.( I am not aware of an alfresco module doing ocr or barcode reading)

2)After upload via webdav, you have to run alfresco metadata extract action, which will have to extract the customer and type from the documents metadata into alfresco metadata by using an alfresco rule script or behaviour.

- Using a rule, you can choose the action "extract common metadata fields"
- Using a java behaviour, you can call the same action like this:
  Action action = actionService.createAction("extract-metadata");
          actionService.executeAction(action, node);

This extract action is described here : https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Metadata_Extraction . You may have to add custom code for your barcode requirement. (https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Content_Transformation_and_Metadata_Extraction_with_Apache_Tika )

3)an alfresco rule script or behaviour is now able to move your document by reading this alfresco metadata property.

Comment: Hi Stefan. Do you have an example howto extract metadata? I'm not sure if I have to program this by hand by using WebScript/Java or if this is configurable via UI (Aflresco-Share)

Comment: I ve added more info in the answer

Comment: Thank you Stefan, your additions pointed me to the right place.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good howto about custom types and let me deep dive into Alfresco:

http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/content/tutorial/tutorial.html

Alfresco Developer Tutorials: http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series